# Retrieve content of iframe within iframe jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am having trouble retrieving the contents of an iframe that is embedded within an iframe with jQuery.

The following code returns the child iframe successfully:

```
$('#someid iframe').contents().find('iframe')
```

However, if I try and get the contents of this returned iframe I get nothing:

```
$('#someid iframe').contents().find('iframe').contents()
```

Is there a problem with chaining .contents()? Is this even possible?

Comment: Are all the iframes in the same domain?

Comment: Ahh! they are not, the inner one is remote. So I presume this is JavaScripts cross domain limitation?

Comment: Maybe by the time your javascript function is called, the content of the inner iframe is not loaded yet!

Comment: I did have the same thought, but even running the code in the browser console returns nothing =(

Comment: can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) sample for us?